# Como obtener correctamente la altura del body?

Tags: javascript, html, chrome

Quiero calcular la altura del body de mi sitio, intento multiples formas, pero ninguna me devuelve el tamaño que me devuelve el navegador al inspeccionar el elemento (adjunto imagen al final de la pregunta)

```
document.body.offsetHeight
document.body.innerHeight
document.body.height
```

Probé también esta solución:

```
const body = document.body;
const html = document.documentElement;
const height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
  html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
console.log(height)
```

En todos los casos recibo valores entre 2600 y 2750, cuando el valor que busco es mayor a 4000. Alguien sabe qué propiedad es la que me está mostrando chrome, como el height del elemento? Muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En teoría utilizar `document.body.offsetHeight` es correcto devido a que este lo que hace es devolverte el valor del alto aunque si no me equivoco tiende a redondear el valor en tu caso debería salirte 4138 como resultado

Comment: ahora puede que esté tomando un valor defiente porque no intentas obtener el height pero no desde el body sino desde su id, puede ser una solución

Comment: tal vez ese JS se está ejecutando antes de que aparezcan algunos elementos que hacen que la altura del body aumente. Si pones `document.body.offsetHeight` en la consola qué valor te da?

Comment: @Fedex7501 en consola me da los valores que les comento, unos 1000px menos, el cálculo se hace dentro de la funcion ``mounted`` de ``vue`` la cual espera a que el componente (el index del sitio) se haya terminado de cargar. Le puse un setTimeout(100) dentro del mounted (pésimo jaja) y funcionó. Bastante atado con alambre pero bueno, efectivamente era un problema de tiempos de carga. Muchas gracias

Comment: hmm tendrías que identificar el evento que hace que cambie de tamaño. porque ese timeout te podría dar problemas en el futuro.

Comment: tal vez hay algunas imagenes que tardan en cargar o algo

Comment: document.documentElement.scrollHeigth te proporciona la altura del body, mejor dicho todos los elementos que estan dentro del body, si no hay suficientes elementos como para que se produzca el scroll lo que te da es la altura del viewport.   document.documentElement.clientHeigth da la altura del viewport  y   document.documentElement.scrollTop  la altura de lo que hiciste scroll. Con esas 3 propiedades puedes hacer un infinite scroll si es lo que estas queriendo lograr